# c# Unit tests написать в лог

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты

Как писать в окно отладки в юнит тестировании?

`Trace.WriteLine()` не работает почему-то. `Debug.` не удобно

Comment: А Log4Net не пробовал? У него очень много гибких настроек.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать в окно отладки во время тестирования можно как с использованием `Console.WriteLine()`, так и с использованием `Trace.WriteLine()`

### *Пример* `Console.WriteLine`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConsoleWriteLine()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
    Console.WriteLine(@"Тест 'TestConsoleWriteLine' успешно пройден");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### *Пример* `Trace.WriteLine`

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTraceWriteLine()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
    Trace.WriteLine(@"Тест 'TestTraceWriteLine' успешно пройден");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не работает ни одним из указанных способов - необходимо смотреть настройки `VisualStudio` и `Resharper`. Перейдите в настройки `Resharper -> Options... -> Tools -> Unit Testing` и посмотрите, как у Вас там настроено, попробуйте внести изменения. Хотя, все зависит от версии `Resharper` и `VisualStudio`.

---

Увидел комментарий по поводу исключения: Если Ваш тест не ожидает `Exception`, необходимо навесить на метод теста аттрибут [ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx), который указывает, что во время выполнения метода теста ожидается исключение.

Comment: Спасибо, Console работает прекрасно в решарпере

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле работает, но немного не так, как обычно. Я запустил простейший тест:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Tracing from test");
    }
}
```

и после его пробега в отчёте (внутри обозревателя тестов) появилась ссылка `Output`.

[image: test explorer]

По ней открывается окно:

[image: а вот и оно]

Да, это не так удобно, как обычно, и вывод появляется только весь и только после пробега теста.

Comment: Плюс туда же идет вывод от `Console.WriteLine()` и `TestContext.WriteLIne()` (если пользоваться MSTest).

Comment: Хм. Странно, когда результаты теста показываются в окне Resharper-a, то в результатах пусто вообще. Похоже придется пользоваться стандартным окном вижуал студии

Comment: @ЯктенсТид: Возможно, решарпер перенаправляет отладочный вывод ещё куда-то?

Comment: Не знаю. По моему вообще баг какой то. Добавил в юнит тест throw new Exception();, так решарпер вообще инфу не выводит, только пишет, что тест не проешл

Comment: @ЯктенсТид: Да, выглядит как баг. Если вы за решарпер заплатили деньги, обратитесь в поддержку, пусть чинят.